# ForeignObject not displaying in Firefox, but is in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I am trying to fix a rendering bug with my program, which currently works perfectly in Chrome and Edge. Firefox does not render the foreignObjects at all

I am using the SVG.js library, which produces the code below for one of my foreignObjects. I have tried a fix from an earlier question, which was to use the css code below to no effect.

```
<foreignObject width="256" height="66" x="76" y="1113">
<span id="run" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<button type="button" id="runButton" class="userButtons" style="width:133px;height:65px">RUN</button>
</span>
</foreignObject>
```

```
svg {
overflow: visible;
}
```

If anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely, your svg doesn't have a explicit height.
Try to add a viewBox and height/width properties:

```css
svg{
  overflow: visible;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.scroll{
  height:900px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 256 66" width="256px" height="66">
 <foreignObject width="256" height="66" x="76" y="500">
    <span id="run" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <button type="button" id="runButton" class="userButtons" style="width:133px;height:65px">RUN</button>
    </span>
</foreignObject>
</svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have implemented the foreignObject using your code above and that works perfectly, however when i try tro do the same with the SVG.js library I stilll encounter the issue. I will try some more, but thank you for the help so far